# Barcode EAN-13 to binary

Tags: java, barcode

I need create byte array from EAN-13 digits.
How I understend, here is description: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_%28EAN%29#Binary_encoding_of_data_digits_into_EAN-13_barcode

Maybe someone already created this algorithm? Please share.

Comment: What is the byte array supposed to contain? Should each bit represent one pixel along the horizontal axis? If yes, should it contain the mandatory white space on both sides of the bar code as well?

Comment: I know just: 1) Barcode type BitLine; 2) Barcode 4821111111111 equals byte[] b = {0x30, 0x30, 0x35, 0x36, 0x45, 0x36, 0x43, 0x43, 0x39, 0x39, 0x36, 0x36, 0x43, 0x44, 0x35, 0x39, 0x42, 0x33, 0x36, 0x36, 0x43, 0x44, 0x39, 0x42, 0x33, 0x35, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30}

Comment: Your byte array is in fact an array of hexadecimal characters (in ASCII). It represents the following string: 0056e6cc9966cd59b366cd9b35000000. If this string is converted into 16 bytes of binary data it indeed contains the pixel pattern of a barcode, which starts after 9 zero bits and ends with 24 zero bits.

Comment: Sorry, but I not understend how convert ean-13 to this String. Can you show any example?

Answer (score 0):

The following code could encodes an EAN-13 barcode. The `funnyEncode` method is the special version you seem to require.

```
public class EAN13Encoder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] result = encode(4821111111111L);
        result = funnyEncode(4821111111111L);
    }

    public static byte[] encode(long ean) {
        EAN13Encoder encoder = new EAN13Encoder(12);
        encoder.buildBars(getDigitArray(ean));
        return encoder.getByteArray();
    }

    public static byte[] funnyEncode(long ean) {
        EAN13Encoder encoder = new EAN13Encoder(16);
        encoder.moveBitPos(9);
        encoder.buildBars(getDigitArray(ean));
        byte[] byteArray = encoder.getByteArray();
        return hexEncode(byteArray);
    }

    private byte[] byteArray;
    private int bitPos = 0;

    private EAN13Encoder(int byteArrayLength) {
        byteArray = new byte[byteArrayLength];
    }

    private byte[] getByteArray() {
        return byteArray;
    }

    private void moveBitPos(int diff) {
        bitPos += diff;
    }

    public static int[] getDigitArray(long ean) {
        int[] digitArray = new int[13];
        int index = 12;
        while (ean > 0) {
            digitArray[index] = (int)(ean % 10);
            ean = ean / 10;
            index--;
        }
        return digitArray;
    }

    private void buildBars(int[] digitArray) {
        // left synchronization bars
        addBits(3, 0x05);

        // left half
        int firstDigit = digitArray[0];
        int lg_switch = LG_SWITCH[firstDigit];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            int digit = digitArray[i + 1];
            int pattern = (lg_switch & (0x20 >> i)) == 0 ? L_BARS[digit] : G_BARS[digit];
            addBits(7, pattern);
        }

        // middle synchronization bars
        addBits(5, 0x0a);

        // right half
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            int digit = digitArray[i + 7];
            int pattern = R_BARS[digit];
            addBits(7, pattern);
        }

        // right synchronization bars
        addBits(3, 0x05);
    }

    private void addBits(int numBits, int pattern) {
        int currentBytePos = bitPos >> 3;
        int remainingBits = 8 - (bitPos & 0x07);
        byte currentByte = byteArray[currentBytePos];
        if (numBits <= remainingBits) {
            currentByte = (byte)(currentByte | (pattern << (remainingBits - numBits)));
        } else {
            currentByte = (byte)(currentByte | (pattern >> (numBits - remainingBits)));
            byteArray[currentBytePos] = currentByte;
            currentBytePos++;
            currentByte = (byte)(pattern << (8 - (numBits - remainingBits)));
        }
        byteArray[currentBytePos] = currentByte;
        bitPos += numBits;
    }

    private static byte[] hexEncode(byte[] src) {
        byte[] dest = new byte[src.length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
            dest[i * 2] = HEX_DIGITS[(src[i] & 0xff) >>> 4];
            dest[i * 2 + 1] = HEX_DIGITS[src[i] & 0x0f];
        }
        return dest;
    }

    private static final int[] LG_SWITCH = { 0x00, 0x0b, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x13, 0x19, 0x1c, 0x15, 0x16, 0x1a };    
    private static final int[] L_BARS = { 0x0d, 0x19, 0x13, 0x3d, 0x23, 0x31, 0x2f, 0x3b, 0x37, 0x0b };
    private static final int[] G_BARS = { 0x27, 0x33, 0x1b, 0x21, 0x1d, 0x39, 0x05, 0x11, 0x09, 0x17 };
    private static final int[] R_BARS = { 0x72, 0x66, 0x6c, 0x42, 0x5c, 0x4e, 0x50, 0x44, 0x48, 0x74 };
    private static final byte[] HEX_DIGITS = { 0x30, 0x31, 032, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46 };
}
```